# There is already an object named 'PK_BaseEnquiries_EnquiryID_DSAR' in the database

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that creates a temporary table with a primary key, but every now and then the above exception is thrown.

This occurs in a .NET web application that uses Entity Framework. For the most part queries are written in LINQ, apart from reports that use stored procedures.

I'm as sure as I can be that connections are not persisted between report executions, but even if they were the table would be deleted, or an exception would show that the table already exists.

It's almost as if the key has global scope even though the table does not.

This is the SQL to create the table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #BaseEnquiries;
CREATE TABLE #BaseEnquiries (EnquiryId BIGINT NOT NULL, Date DATE NULL, SalesExecId BIGINT NOT NULL, SalesExecName NVARCHAR(100), 
                            DealerId BIGINT NOT NULL, DealerName NVARCHAR(100), FranchiseId BIGINT, FranchiseName NVARCHAR(100), 
                            FirstContactTypeId BIGINT, CustomerId BIGINT NOT NULL, EnquiryDateString NVARCHAR(50), EnquiryDateNumber BIGINT,
                            CONSTRAINT PK_BaseEnquiries_EnquiryID_DSAR PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (EnquiryID));
```

The DROP TABLE was added to attempt to resolve the problem, but it clearly doesn't.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Have u used this constraint in some other table. Select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS where Constraint_name ='PK_BaseEnquiries_EnquiryID_DSAR'

Comment: No, this constraint is only used for this table and only for this stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

`PK_BaseEnquiries_EnquiryID_DSAR` is, in fact, global to the tempdb database.

Perhaps you have another SQL Connection open to the same server which still has a `#BaseEnquiries` table in scope with its own `PK_BaseEnquiries_EnquiryID_DSAR` constraint.

It's generally bad form to name constraints on #temp and ##temp tables for exactly this reason. You'd avoid the issue by using `create table #BaseEnquiries (EnquiryId BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Date DATE, ...`

Comment: I thought this but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: It's generally bad form to name constraints on #temp and ##temp tables for exactly this reason. You'd avoid the issue by using `create table #BaseEnquiries (EnquiryId BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Date DATE, ...`

Comment: That's a good idea - I didn't think of that. You should update your answer with that.